# Rounding time to nearest quarter hour

Tags: r, datetime

I have a vector of POSIXct values and I would like to round them to the nearest quarter hour. I don't care about the day. How do I convert the values to hours and minutes?

For example, I would like the value

```
"2012-05-30 20:41:21 UTC"
```

to be

```
"20:45"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Indeed, an old question with some helpful answers so far. The last one by giraffhere seems to be the most elegant. however, ist not floor_date but round_date which will do the trick:

```
lubridate::round_date(x, "15 minutes")
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use `round`. The trick is to divide by 900 seconds (15 minutes * 60 seconds) before rounding and multiply by 900 afterwards:

```
a <-as.POSIXlt("2012-05-30 20:41:21 UTC")
b <-as.POSIXlt(round(as.double(a)/(15*60))*(15*60),origin=(as.POSIXlt('1970-01-01')))
b
[1] "2012-05-30 20:45:00 EDT"
```

To get only hour and minute, just use format

```
format(b,"%H:%M")
[1] "20:45"

as.character(format(b,"%H:%M"))
[1] "20:45"
```

Comment: I don't think we need a double, and origin accepts a string, so slightly simplified: `b <-as.POSIXlt(round(as.numeric(a)/(15*60))*(15*60),origin='1970-01-01')`

Comment: Since `R4.3.*` we no longer need to explicitly specify the origin if it's the unix epoch as in this case.

Answer (score 15):

something like

```
format(strptime("1970-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d", tz="UTC") + round(as.numeric(your.time)/900)*900,"%H:%M")
```

would work

Answer (score 14):

Old question, but would like to note that the `lubridate` package handles this easily now with `floor_date`. To cut a vector of POSIXct objects to 15 minute intervals, use like this.

`x <- lubridate::floor_date(x, "15 minutes")`

EDIT: Noted by user @user3297928, use `lubridate::round_date(x, "15 minutes")` for rounding to the nearest 15 minutes. The above floors it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `align.time` function in the xts package to handle the rounding, then `format` to return a string of "HH:MM":

```
R> library(xts)
R> p <- as.POSIXct("2012-05-30 20:41:21", tz="UTC")
R> a <- align.time(p, n=60*15)  # n is in seconds
R> format(a, "%H:%M")
[1] "20:45"
```

Comment: This is elegant, but seems to only round up.

Comment: @Dominic: you're 100% correct. `align.time` only rounds up and you wanted to round to the nearest quarter-hour. Apologies.

Comment: to round down: `align.time(p - lubridate::minutes(15), n=60*15)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this, which combines both requests and is based on looking at what `round.POSIXt()` and `trunc.POSIXt()` do.

```
myRound <- function (x, convert = TRUE)  {
    x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
    mins <- x$min
    mult <- mins %/% 15
    remain <- mins %% 15
    if(remain > 7L || (remain == 7L && x$sec > 29))
        mult <- mult + 1
    if(mult > 3) {
        x$min <- 0
        x <- x + 3600
    } else {
        x$min <- 15 * mult
    }
    x <- trunc.POSIXt(x, units = "mins")
    if(convert) {
        x <- format(x, format = "%H:%M")
    }
    x
}
```

This gives:

```
> tmp <- as.POSIXct("2012-05-30 20:41:21 UTC")
> myRound(tmp)
[1] "20:45"
> myRound(tmp, convert = FALSE)
[1] "2012-05-30 20:45:00 BST"
> tmp2 <- as.POSIXct("2012-05-30 20:55:21 UTC")
> myRound(tmp2)
[1] "21:00"
> myRound(tmp2, convert = FALSE)
[1] "2012-05-30 21:00:00 BST"
```

Comment: this seems to be not vectorized well, try `structure(c(1313331280, 1313334917, 1313334917, 1313340309, 1313340309, 
1313340895, 1313340895, 1313341133, 1313341218, 1313341475), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")`

Answer (score 3):

Using `IDate` and `ITime` classes from `data.table` and a `IPeriod` class (just developed) I was able to get more scalable solution.
Only *shhhhimhuntingrabbits* and *PLapointe* answer the question in terms of *nearest*. `xts` solution only rounds using *ceiling*, my `IPeriod` solution allows to specify *ceiling* or *floor*.
To get top performance you would need to keep your data in `IDate` and `ITime` classes. As seen on benchmark it is cheap to produce `POSIXct` from `IDate/ITime/IPeriod`. Below benchmark of some 22M timestamp:

```
# install only if you don't have
install.packages(c("microbenchmarkCore","data.table"),
                 repos = c("https://olafmersmann.github.io/drat",
                           "https://jangorecki.github.io/drat/iperiod"))
library(microbenchmarkCore)
library(data.table) # iunit branch
library(xts)
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

## some source data: download and unzip csv
# "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/btceUSD.csv.gz"
# below benchmark on btceUSD.csv.gz 11-Oct-2015 11:35 133664801

system.nanotime(dt <- fread(".btceUSD.csv"))
# Read 21931266 rows and 3 (of 3) columns from 0.878 GB file in 00:00:10
#     user   system  elapsed 
#       NA       NA 9.048991

# take the timestamp only
x = as.POSIXct(dt[[1L]], tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01")

# functions
shhhhi <- function(your.time){
    strptime("1970-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d", tz="UTC") + round(as.numeric(your.time)/900)*900
}

PLapointe <- function(a){
    as.POSIXlt(round(as.double(a)/(15*60))*(15*60),origin=(as.POSIXlt('1970-01-01')))
}

# myRound - not vectorized

# compare results
all.equal(
    format(shhhhi(x),"%H:%M"),
    format(PLapointe(x),"%H:%M")
)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(
    format(align.time(x, n = 60*15),"%H:%M"),
    format(periodize(x, "mins", 15),"%H:%M")
)
# [1] TRUE

# IPeriod native input are IDate and ITime - will be tested too
idt <- IDateTime(x)
idate <- idt$idate
itime <- idt$itime
microbenchmark(times = 10L,
               shhhhi(x),
               PLapointe(x),
               xts = align.time(x, 15*60),
               posix_ip_posix = as.POSIXct(periodize(x, "mins", 15), tz="UTC"),
               posix_ip = periodize(x, "mins", 15),
               ip_posix = as.POSIXct(periodize(idate, itime, "mins", 15), tz="UTC"),
               ip = periodize(idate, itime, "mins", 15))
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr         min          lq         mean       median          uq         max neval
#       shhhhi(x)  960819.810  984970.363 1127272.6812 1167512.2765 1201770.895 1243706.235    10
#    PLapointe(x) 2322929.313 2440263.122 2617210.4264 2597772.9825 2792936.774 2981499.356    10
#             xts  453409.222  525738.163  581139.6768  546300.9395  677077.650  767609.155    10
#  posix_ip_posix 3314609.993 3499220.920 3641219.0876 3586822.9150 3654548.885 4457614.174    10
#        posix_ip 3010316.462 3066736.299 3157777.2361 3133693.0655 3234307.549 3401388.800    10
#        ip_posix     335.741     380.696     513.7420     543.3425     630.020     663.385    10
#              ip      98.031     151.471     207.7404     231.8200     262.037     278.789    10
```

`IDate` and `ITime` successfully scales not only in this particular task. Both types, same as `IPeriod`, are integer based. I would assume they will also scale nice on join or grouping by *datetime* fields.
Online manual: https://jangorecki.github.io/drat/iperiod/

Comment: Thanks for the post, but can you explain how to actually _install_ this package? It's not clear anywhere from the documentation.

Comment: @ssdecontrol See first command in the code block to install from published repo. Otherwise the most reliable way is to get the [iunit](https://github.com/jangorecki/data.table/tree/iunit) branch, you can add it to remote and checkout to branch. It is based on Oct 2015 data.table.

Comment: Ah, I missed that line. I had assumed you would have a separate package called "periodize" or "IPeriod" or something, as opposed to a fork of data.table. I think it's somewhat unfortunate that the `IDateTime` stuff is bundled into data.table and not a separate package

Comment: @ssdecontrol but IPeriod class is just a numeric, any package can handle it just with `%/%` operator, having periods hardcoded there is even no need to store any attributes, just a number, no black magic.

Comment: Abstraction is valuable imo

Comment: @ssdecontrol agree, but extracting just that to a separate package isn't so necessary as data.table is a lightweight dependency already. Can be imported just for IDateTime without hassle. Be aware there is planned an extensions to IDateTime classes data.table [data.table#1451](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1451), would be nice to IPeriod handle nanoseconds too.