# aggregate 1-minute data into 5-minute average data

Tags: r, date

My question here is to aggregate the data collected at every 1-minute into 5-minute average.

```
DeviceTime         Concentration
6/20/2013 11:13       
6/20/2013 11:14
6/20/2013 11:15
6/20/2013 11:16
6/20/2013 11:17
6/20/2013 11:18
6/20/2013 11:19
6/20/2013 11:20
6/20/2013 11:21
6/20/2013 11:22
6/20/2013 11:23
6/20/2013 11:24
6/20/2013 11:25
6/20/2013 11:26
6/20/2013 11:27
6/20/2013 11:28
```

...

The result I want is like:

```
DeviceTime             Concentration
6/20/2013 11:15
6/20/2013 11:20
6/20/2013 11:25
6/20/2013 11:30
6/20/2013 11:35
...
```

The 5-minute average is just the simple average over the concentration in the past five minutes.

Comment: `cut` can work on date/time objects with breaks set as, say, "5 min"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108515/how-to-round-a-time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregate values of 15 minute steps to values of hourly steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389533/aggregate-values-of-15-minute-steps-to-values-of-hourly-steps)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package and assuming, your data is stored in a data frame named `df`:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(DeviceTime = cut(DeviceTime, breaks="5 min")) %>%
  summarize(Concentration = mean(Concentration))
```

Comment: The syntax looks a little bit complicated :)

Comment: Being a comment the layout it's a bit weird, however you can simplify your code in this way lukeA. `df %.%

  group_by(DeviceTime = cut(DeviceTime, breaks="5 min")) %.%

  summarize(Concentration = mean(Concentration))`

Comment: `cut()` will break on 11:13, 11:18, etc. rather than 5-min wall clock breaks (11:15, 11:20, etc.)  See my answer for a solution which cuts/breaks on wall clock boundaries using package xts.

Answer (score 26):

If your data doesn't start on a nice 5-minute wall clock boundary (as shown in your sample data – 11:13), note that `cut()` will create breakpoints based on the first timestamp it finds.  This probably isn't what we normally want.  Indeed, your sample output indicates this is not what you want.

Here's what `cut()` does:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
DeviceTime,Concentration
6/20/2013 11:13,1
6/20/2013 11:14,1
6/20/2013 11:15,2
6/20/2013 11:16,2
6/20/2013 11:17,2
6/20/2013 11:18,2
6/20/2013 11:19,2
6/20/2013 11:20,3
6/20/2013 11:21,3
6/20/2013 11:22,3
6/20/2013 11:23,3
6/20/2013 11:24,3
6/20/2013 11:25,4")
df$DeviceTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DeviceTime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

cut(df$DeviceTime, breaks="5 min")
 [1] 2013-06-20 11:13:00 2013-06-20 11:13:00 2013-06-20 11:13:00
 [4] 2013-06-20 11:13:00 2013-06-20 11:13:00 2013-06-20 11:18:00
 [7] 2013-06-20 11:18:00 2013-06-20 11:18:00 2013-06-20 11:18:00
[10] 2013-06-20 11:18:00 2013-06-20 11:23:00 2013-06-20 11:23:00
[13] 2013-06-20 11:23:00

means <- aggregate(df["Concentration"], 
                   list(fiveMin=cut(df$DeviceTime, "5 mins")),
                   mean)
means
              fiveMin Concentration
1 2013-06-20 11:13:00      1.600000
2 2013-06-20 11:18:00      2.600000
3 2013-06-20 11:23:00      3.333333
```

Notice that the first row of `means` (the 11:13:00 entry) is the mean of the first 5 rows of `df`, which have times of 11:13 to 11:17 -- i.e., up until just before the next cut/break point of 11:18.

You'll get the same result with dplyr (i.e., @lukeA's answer) if you use `cut()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(DeviceTime = cut(DeviceTime, breaks="5 min")) %>%
  summarize(Concentration = mean(Concentration))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

           DeviceTime Concentration
1 2013-06-20 11:13:00      1.600000
2 2013-06-20 11:18:00      2.600000
3 2013-06-20 11:23:00      3.333333
```

The xts package seems to break by wall clock time:

```
require(xts)
df.xts <- xts(df$Concentration, df$DeviceTime)
means.xts <- period.apply(df.xts, endpoints(df.xts, "mins", k=5), mean)
means.xts
                    [,1]
2013-06-20 11:14:00    1
2013-06-20 11:19:00    2
2013-06-20 11:24:00    3
2013-06-20 11:25:00    4
```

The time values are always the last time entry found in the 5-min window.  You can round the time index column up the the next 5-min boundary with `align.time()`, if you want to report the times of the end of the periods:

```
means.rounded <- align.time(means.xts, 5*60)
means.rounded
                    [,1]
2013-06-20 11:15:00    1
2013-06-20 11:20:00    2
2013-06-20 11:25:00    3
2013-06-20 11:30:00    4
```

You can also round down, if you want to report the times of the beginning of the periods.  But you'll need to define your own function first (which I found on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/how-to-re-sample-an-xts-time-series-in-r/19003#19003)):

```
align.time.down = function(x,n) {
    index(x) = index(x) - n
    align.time(x,n)
}
means.rounded.down <- align.time.down(means.xts, 5*60)
means.rounded.down
                    [,1]
2013-06-20 11:10:00    1
2013-06-20 11:15:00    2
2013-06-20 11:20:00    3
2013-06-20 11:25:00    4
```

---

Another solution, that doesn't use the xts package, but rather `floor()`, is as follows:

```
df$DeviceTimeFloor <- as.POSIXct(floor(as.numeric(df$DeviceTime) / (5 * 60)) * (5 * 60), origin='1970-01-01')
meansFloor <- aggregate(Concentration ~ DeviceTimeFloor, df, mean)
meansFloor
      DeviceTimeFloor Concentration
1 2013-06-20 11:10:00             1
2 2013-06-20 11:15:00             2
3 2013-06-20 11:20:00             3
4 2013-06-20 11:25:00             4
```

I prefer to report the start time of the 5-minute interval – `floor()` is good for this.  Because, if I were to report aggregates by hour, I would expect a timestamp of 2013-06-20 11:00:00 to contain data for the period 11:00:00 - 11:59:59 not 10:00:00 - 10:59:59.

If you prefer to report the end time of the intervals, `ceiling()` can be used instead of `floor()`.  But note that timestamps 11:01 - 11:05 will be converted to (and hence grouped at) 11:05 by `ceiling()`.  In contrast, `floor()` converts 11:00 - 11:04 to 11:00.

**So they each group a different set of observations.**  The xts package will group the same set of observations as `floor()`, but it will report the last timestamp of the last observation in the period.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the easiest and cleanest way to do this is using the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages.

```
library(lubridate)  # for working with dates
library(dplyr)      # for manipulating data

df$DeviceTime5min <- floor_date(df$DeviceTime, "5 mins")
df_5min <- df %>% group_by(DeviceTime5min) %>% summarize(mean(Concentration))
```

Only problem here is that it works just for values, that fit into an hour ... that is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60 min. But for these it works perfect :-)