# Summarize values for overlapping time periods

Tags: r

I'm trying to summarize values for overlapping time periods.
I can use only tidyr, ggplot2 and dplyr libraries. Base R is preferred though.

My data looks like this, but usually it has around 100 records:

```
df <- structure(list(Start = structure(c(1546531200, 1546531200, 546531200, 1546638252.6316, 1546549800, 1546534800, 1546545600, 1546531200, 1546633120, 1547065942.1053), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Stop = structure(c(1546770243.1579, 1546607400, 1547110800, 1546670652.6316, 1547122863.1579, 1546638252.6316, 1546878293.5579, 1546416000, 1546849694.4, 1547186400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Value = c(12610, 520, 1500, 90, 331380, 27300, 6072, 4200, 61488, 64372)), .Names = c("Start", "Stop", "Value"), row.names = c(41L, 55L, 25L, 29L, 38L, 28L, 1L, 20L, 14L, 31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`head(df)` and `str(df)` gives:

```
          Start                Stop      Value
2019-01-03 16:00:00 2019-01-06 10:24:03  12610
2019-01-03 16:00:00 2019-01-04 13:10:00    520
2019-01-03 16:00:00 2019-01-10 09:00:00   1500
2019-01-04 21:44:12 2019-01-05 06:44:12     90
2019-01-03 21:10:00 2019-01-10 12:21:03 331380
2019-01-03 17:00:00 2019-01-04 21:44:12  27300

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Start: POSIXct, format: "2019-01-03 16:00:00" "2019-01-03 16:00:00" ...
 $ Stop : POSIXct, format: "2019-01-06 10:24:03" "2019-01-04 13:10:00" ...
 $ Value: num  12610 520 1500 90 331380 ...
```

So there are overlapping time periods with "Start" and "Stop" dates with assigned value. In any given record when there is a value between `df$Start` and `df$Stop` and outside of this scope the value is 0.

I want to create another dataframe based on which I could show how this values summarize and change over time. The Desired output would look like this (the "sum" column is made up):

```
> head(df2)
              timestamp     sum
"2019-01-02 09:00:00 CET"   14352
"2019-01-03 17:00:00 CET"   6253
"2019-01-03 18:00:00 CET"   23465
"2019-01-03 21:00:00 CET"   3241
"2019-01-03 22:10:00 CET"   23235
"2019-01-04 14:10:00 CET"   123321
```

To get unique timestamps:

```
timestamps <- sort(unique(c(df$`Start`, df$`Stop`)))
```

With `df2` dataframe I could easily draw a graph with ggplot, but how to get this sums?

I think I should iterate over `df` data frame either some custom function or any built-it summarize function which would work like this:

```
fnct <- function(date, min, max, value) {
  if (date >= min && date <=max) {
    a <- value
  }
  else {
  a <- 0
  }
  return(a)
}
```

...for every given `date` from `timestamps` iterate through `df` and give me a sum of values for the `timestamp`.

It looks really simple and I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: there is an error in your sample data: `2019-01-03 16:00:00
2019-01-02 08:00:00
4200`, `Stop` is before `Start`

Comment: I didn't notice it while writing my post, but unfortunately in this case I'm dealing with it was originally there. Some of the data is human dependent, so errors like this will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution similar to my response to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000814/in-r-how-do-i-split-timestamp-interval-data-into-regular-slots/54002358?noredirect=1#comment94869475_54002358). I gather to bring the timestamps (Starts and Stops) into one column, with another column specifying which. The Starts add the value and the Stops subtract it, and then we just take the cumulative sum to get values at all the instants when the sum changes.

For 100 records, there won't be any perceivable speed improvement from using data.table; in my experience it starts to make more of a difference around 1M records, especially when grouping is involved.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  gather(type, time, Start:Stop) %>%
  mutate(chg = if_else(type == "Start", Value, -Value)) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(sum = cumsum(chg)) # EDIT: corrected per OP comment

> head(df2)
## A tibble: 6 x 5
#  Value type  time                   chg    sum
#  <dbl> <chr> <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  1500 Start 1987-04-27 14:13:20   1500   1500
#2  4200 Stop  2019-01-02 08:00:00  -4200  -2700
#3 12610 Start 2019-01-03 16:00:00  12610   9910
#4   520 Start 2019-01-03 16:00:00    520  10430
#5  4200 Start 2019-01-03 16:00:00   4200  14630
#6 27300 Start 2019-01-03 17:00:00  27300  41930
```

Comment: It the last line there should be `cumsum(chg)`, not `cumsum(Value)`. Otherwise the sum column always goes up. But other than this it's a nice and simple solution. Also, for my solution, as @Wimpel noticed, there should be a filter to remove not correct data: `dt <- dt[ Start < Stop, ]`, which I added.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have tried to solve similar problems using the tidyverse/baseR... But nothing comes even remotely close to the speeds that `data.table` provides for these kind of operations, so I encourage you to give it a try...

For questions like this, my favourite finction is `foverlaps()` from the `data.table`-package. With this function you can (fast!) perform an overlap-join. If you want more flexibility in your joining than `foverlaps()` provides, a `non-equi`-join (again using `data.table`) is probably the best (and fastest!) option. But `foverlaps()` will do here (I guess).

I used the sample data you provided, but filtered out rows where `Stop <= Start` (probably a tyop in your sample data). When `df$Start` is not before `df$Stop`, `foverlaps` give a warning and won't execute.

```
library( data.table )

#create data.table with periods you wish to simmarise on
#NB: UTC is used as timezone, since this is also the case in the sample data provided!!
dt.dates <- data.table( id = paste0( "Day", 1:31 ),
                        Start = seq( as.POSIXct( "2019-01-01 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ),
                                     as.POSIXct( "2019-01-31 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ),
                                     by = "1 days"),
                        Stop = seq( as.POSIXct( "2019-01-02 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ) - 1,
                                    as.POSIXct( "2019-02-01 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ) - 1,
                                    by = "1 days") )
```

If you do not want to summarise on a daily basis, but by hour, minute, second, of year. Just change the values (and stepsize) in `dt.dates` data.table so that they match your periods.

```
#set df as data.table
dt <- as.data.table( df )
#filter out any row where Stop is smaller than Start
dt <- dt[ Start < Stop, ]

#perform overlap join
#first set keys
setkey(dt, Start, Stop)
#then perform join
result <- foverlaps( dt.dates, dt, type = "within" )
#summarise
result[, .( Value = sum( Value , na.rm = TRUE ) ), by = .(Day = i.Start) ]
```

**output**

```
#            Day  Value
#  1: 2019-01-01   1500
#  2: 2019-01-02   1500
#  3: 2019-01-03   1500
#  4: 2019-01-04 351562
#  5: 2019-01-05 413050
#  6: 2019-01-06 400440
#  7: 2019-01-07 332880
#  8: 2019-01-08 332880
#  9: 2019-01-09 332880
# 10: 2019-01-10  64372
# 11: 2019-01-11      0
# 12: 2019-01-12      0
# 13: 2019-01-13      0
# 14: 2019-01-14      0
# 15: 2019-01-15      0
# 16: 2019-01-16      0
# 17: 2019-01-17      0
# 18: 2019-01-18      0
# 19: 2019-01-19      0
# 20: 2019-01-20      0
# 21: 2019-01-21      0
# 22: 2019-01-22      0
# 23: 2019-01-23      0
# 24: 2019-01-24      0
# 25: 2019-01-25      0
# 26: 2019-01-26      0
# 27: 2019-01-27      0
# 28: 2019-01-28      0
# 29: 2019-01-29      0
# 30: 2019-01-30      0
# 31: 2019-01-31      0
#            Day  Value
```

**plot**

```
#summarise for plot
result.plot <- result[, .( Value = sum( Value , na.rm = TRUE ) ), by = .(Day = i.Start) ]
library( ggplot2 )
ggplot( data = result.plot, aes( x = Day, y = Value ) ) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like a good solution if I'd change "1 days", for "1 hour", but I can't test it, because I have access only to the libraries I mentioned. Thank you anyway, I'll be aware of that in the future solutions of such problems. Also good point about the correctness of the data, I've added filter you suggested to my solution.