# Speeding up a double loop R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, purrr

I´m have a dataset with arrival times (year-month-day-hour-minute) and attended times on every row for 4 client types and 110 branches. With this two variables I´m trying to create a new column with the queue length for each row (e.g. clientes that arrive earlier than the arrival time of the given transaction but haven´t been attended).

My code below is working but it has been running for A LOT of time. Any ideas on how to speed up this code?

```
library(tidyverse)    
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

transaccion_data<- tibble(transaction_Id = seq(1:10),
arrival_time = c("2018-11-01 09:05:00 CST", "2018-11-01 09:03:00 CST"),
attended_time =c("2018-11-01 09:10:00 CST", "2018-11-01 09:06:00 CST"), 
queue = c(NA, NA))

hours<-seq(ymd_hms("2018-11-01 09:00:00 CST"),ymd_hms("2018-11-01 16:00:00 CST"), 60)
```

`queue_matrix` is a data table with nrow = 9 to 16 hrs (1 minute diferencce) for every day in november and columns is equal to client_type&branch (452 columns)

```
queue_matrix[1:13441, ] <-parSapply(cl = cluster,
  function (x) transaction_data %>%
  group_by(branch_type_client) %>%
  summarise(queue = sum(arrival_time <= x & attended_time>x)) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "branch_type_client") %>%
  transpose()
)
```

Comment: There's no magic way to speed up any code. Have you taken the time to [profile your code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) so you know exactly what's taking up time? What exactly is "A LOT" of time? What do you expect to be reasonable for the amount of data you have?

Comment: I think it will be much faster to first compute the cumulative count for each type & branch at the times of each arrival and attendance, and then integrate that into the sequence of hours, as opposed to doing the calculation for every transaction against every time.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000814/in-r-how-do-i-split-timestamp-interval-data-into-regular-slots/54002358?noredirect=1#comment94869475_54002358

Comment: @JonSpring I didn’t see your comment until I’d already posted my answer. What I’ve done with my answer is broadly similar in principle to the other question, although my implementation is a little different. I agree though that this question should be regarded as a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a bit small (and incomplete) to work with, so I've generated my own:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rlang)
n_items <- 1e6
sample_data <- tibble(
  arrival_time = make_date(2018, 11, floor(runif(n_items, 1, 31))) +
    dhours(9) + dseconds(floor(runif(n_items, 0, 6 * 60 * 60 + 1))),
  attended_time = arrival_time +
    dseconds(floor(runif(n_items, 0, 60 * 60 + 1))),
  branch_type_client = sample(LETTERS, n_items, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Now we need to work out the number of people arriving and attending by each whole minute. I'm assuming someone arriving at 13:05:01 doesn't get counted until 13:06:00.

```
arrived <- sample_data %>% 
  count(branch_type_client, time = ceiling_date(arrival_time, "minutes"))

attended <- sample_data %>% 
  count(branch_type_client, time = ceiling_date(attended_time, "minutes"))
```

Now we join the two together, fill in all of the desired date sequence, and then work out the cumulative difference between arrived and attended.

```
all_times <- rep(seq(ymd("2018-11-01"), ymd("2018-11-30"), by = "1 day"), each = 7 * 60 + 1) +
  dhours(9) + rep(dminutes(0:(60 * 7)), 30)

queue <- full_join(arrived, attended, by = c("branch_type_client", "time"),
                   suffix = c("_arrived", "_attended")) %>% 
  complete(branch_type_client, time = all_times) %>% 
  replace_na(list(n_arrived = 0, n_attended = 0)) %>% 
  arrange(branch_type_client, time) %>% 
  group_by(branch_type_client) %>% 
  mutate(queue_length = cumsum(n_arrived - n_attended))
```

If you want one column per branch_type_client, you can use `tidyr::spread`:

```
queue_wide <- queue %>% 
  select(time, branch_type_client, queue_length) %>% 
  spread(branch_type_client, queue_length)
```

This whole thing (including generating the sample data of a million rows) takes about 6 seconds on my 7-year-old laptop with no parallelisation.