# How to conduct timeseries analysis on half-hourly data?

Tags: r, time-series

I have the dataset below with half hourly timeseries data.

```
Date <- c("2018-01-01 08:00:00", "2018-01-01 08:30:00", 
          "2018-01-01 08:59:59","2018-01-01 09:29:59")
Volume <- c(195, 188, 345, 123)
Dataset <- data.frame(Date, Volume)
```

I would like to know how to read this dataframe in order to conduct time series analysis. How should I define starting and ending date and what the frequency will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "half hour data" since it isn't. In case you want to round it to half hours, we can adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862309/6574038) to your case.

```
Dataset$Date <- as.POSIXlt(round(as.double(Dataset$Date)/(30*60))*(30*60),
                       origin=(as.POSIXlt('1970-01-01')))
```

In case you don't want to round it just do

```
Dataset$Date <- as.POSIXct(Dataset$Date)
```

Basically your `Date` column should be formatted to a date format, e.g. `"POSIXlt"` so that e.g.:

```
> class(Dataset$Date)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Then we can convert the data into time series with `xts`.

```
library(xts)
Dataset.xts <- xts(Dataset$Volume, order.by=Dataset$Date)
```

***Result (rounded case):***

```
> Dataset.xts
[,1]
2018-01-01 08:00:00  195
2018-01-01 08:30:00  188
2018-01-01 09:00:00  345
2018-01-01 09:30:00  123
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dplyr` and `lubridate` from `tidyverse` to get the data into a POSIX date format, then convert to time series with `ts`. Within that you can define parameters.

```
Dataset2 <- Dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.character(Date),
         Date = ymd_hms(Date)) %>% 
  ts(start = c(2018, 1), end = c(2018, 2), frequency = 1)
```

try `?ts` for more details on the parameters. Personally I think `zoo` and `xts` provide a better framework for time series analysis.